# Is it possible to comment on a facebook post using php?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am developing a website where i must be able to comment onto public facebook pages and comment on posts already published on their page through php. Currently i have succeeded in being able to publish posts on a public page where the owner allows people to publish on their page but i am really struggling with trying to comment on a post already on their page with php. Does anybody know if it is even possible to do? I reckon i have to use the object id of the post and try and post to that but so far no luck

Comment: Found the answer out myself, was actually quite easy in the end, just use:  $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/POST-ID/comments', 'POST', array('message' => "$message"));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**/comments**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/object/comments/#publish) to publish comments on a post.

```
POST /POST-ID/comments
```

Parameter: `message`

Permissions required: `publish_actions`